# Is it possible to use C++'s sort in C?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am writing C code but have to do a lot of calls to qsort which is taking most of the time. I notice that C++'s sort is faster than qsort. Is it possible for me to use it somehow? Here is a MWE in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main(void) {
    int sz;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Enter the size of array::");
    scanf("%d",&sz);
    uint32_t *arr = malloc(sz * sizeof *arr);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
        arr[i]=rand(); 
    clock_t begin = clock();
    qsort(arr, sz, sizeof *arr, cmpfunc);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f seconds\n", time_spent);
    printf("%d\n", arr[10]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sort time depends on the data being sorted: is it identical in your comaprison?

Comment: `qsort` might be slower because it uses function pointer callbacks, which isn't good design if performance matters. This function was designed in the dinosaur age long before function inlining was invented.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes it is.

Comment: No: `srand(time(NULL));` means it is different each time.

Comment: Yeah start with replacing `sz` with a fixed constant instead of user input, then compare results. And as always when asking about performance: pretty please with sugar on top, post your compiler options. Some 9 out 10 of these questions here end up with "Do you even have optimizations enabled? No..."

Comment: Also `return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );` may not behave the same on overflow. Don't do that.

Comment: You can write your own sorting routine (using *quick sort* and/or *merge sort* and/or *selection sort* and/or *radix sort*, ... and/or a mix of [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you suggest?

Comment: You defined the array as `unsigned` where the overflow behaviour is well defined (even if the sequence isn't exactly sorted). But really, you should make the required comparison, not a subtraction. And be consistent with the data type. In the C++ version, is it sorting signed or unsigned data?

Comment: @Anush choose a random constant and seed it like this `srand(1234)` to make sure that the generated sequence is the same each time. Or hard code the sorted array. And `return ( *(int*)a > *(int*)b ) - ( *(int*)a < *(int*)b );` to avoid UB

Comment: A proper integer comparison function is `static int cmp_int(const void *va, const void *vb) { const int *a = va, *b = vb; return *a < *b ? -1 : *a > *b; }`.

Comment: That should be `return ( *(uint32_t *)a > *(uint32_t *)b ) - ( *(uint32_t *)a < *(uint32_t *)b );`

Comment: Anush, "I am writing C code but have to do a lot of calls to qsort which is taking most of the time" --> implies the higher level code architecture is weak.  Rather than "Speeding up the sort", consider more fruitful gains with different data structures.  IOWs, what is the higher level task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. C++ is designed to handle such things without much hassle. You need to compile the C++ function separately and then link it to your project:

The header should be valid C and C++. You need to use `extern "C"` by checking if it's C++:

```
// i32sort.h

#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif // __cplusplus
void i32sort(int32_t*, size_t);
```

The source file is straight C++:

```
// i32sort.cpp

#include "i32sort.h"
#include <algorithm>

extern "C" void i32sort(int32_t* const data, size_t const size)
{
    std::sort(data, data + size);
}
```

Then compile it without linking:

```
$ clang++ -c i32sort.cpp -O3 -Wall -Wextra
```

Then include the `i32sort.h` header in your source file as usual:

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "i32sort.h"

int main(void)
{
    int32_t arr[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    size_t const sz = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (* arr);
    i32sort(arr, sz);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        printf("%d ", (int) arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

While compiling your program, link it with the object file you generated previously:

```
$ clang main.c i32sort.o -O3 -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a
1 2 3 4 5
```